# addEventListener for mousedown to Stage in Easel.js

Tags: javascript, dom-events, easeljs

Cannot seem to attach events to Stage.

This is my class:

```
export class Game {
    createCanvas() {
        this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.el);
        createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
        this.attachEvents();
    },

    attachEvents() {
        this.stage.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
            console.debug('mousedown event fired');
        });
    }
}
```

The stage is created just fine. When I use `stagemousedown` instead, it works.  I thought maybe, you can only attach those types of events to a DisplayObject. So, I created a container and added that to the stage but still no luck. It's also unclear to me from the documentation whether or not I need `EventDispatcher` for this.

Comment: A container will only work if it has content. If you create a shape that is the size of the stage, it will work. Stagemousedown is a good alternative, because it will always fire, even if content above it is clicked.

Comment: Okay. So is it best practice to add everything to a container instead of directly to the stage? Also, will a container automatically fill the space of the stage or do you have to set the width and height explicitly?

Comment: Feel free to add it wherever you want. A Container just helps for organizational purposes (and lets you do things like move all objects at once, listen for mouse interaction on all objects, cache things in groups, etc. A container is just a "group" -- it has no hit area of bounds, other than that of its contents.